# how can i work with my GPU in python Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code

Hello I know that the key to analyzing data and working with artificial intelligence is to use the gpu and not the cpu. The problem is that I don't know how to use it with Python in the visual studio code, I use Ubuntu, I already have nvidia installed

Answer (score 1):

You have to use with the libraries that are designed to work with the GPUs.

You can use Numba to compile Python code directly to binary with CUDA/ROC support, but I don't really know how limiting it is.

Another way is to call APIs that are designed for parallel computing such as OpenCL, there is PyOpenCL binding for this.

A bit limiting, but sometimes valid way - OpenGL/DirectX compute shaders, they are extremely easy, but not so fast if you need to transfer data back and forth in small batches.